# Blurry image on list view in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, image, small-image

Although the images are in very good quality in the product view, in the list view have very poor quality and blurry
How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

well its a still debatable  point for me as well I would not able to find proper solution for that.

But let me give you some suggestion for this

put below code in your `img` tag `src` and check if it helps you

```
 <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')
    ->keepAspectRatio(true)
    ->keepFrame(true)
    ->keepTransparency(true)
    ->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255))  
  ->resize($_imgSize)->setQuality(99); ?>
```

Comment: `keepAspectRatio` & `keepTransparency` are `true` by default, `keepFrame` may be relevant here, and `backgroundColor` is only applicable if transparent PNG/GIFs are used. FYI. https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php line 203,236.

Comment: i have did the same but no changes appear in image

Answer (score 1):

Someone else seems to have experienced similar issues with 1.9.2:

- [New products on home page has blurry images after upgrading to Magento ver. 1.9.2.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78110/new-products-on-home-page-has-blurry-images-after-upgrading-to-magento-ver-1-9)

There is a `setQuality` method in the Image helper you can try to bump to see if it helps.  The alternative is to modify the GD2 library code OR give ImageMagick a try instead of GD2 as the filter quality is known to be a bit better.

- setQuality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841236/how-to-deal-with-image-quality-in-magento/10842196#10842196
- GD2 library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8397612/158325
- ImageMagick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255585/bicubic-shaper-php-image-resize/255666#255666